# Todoist Integration with gnome-todo

Tags: python, python-3.x, gnome, webkitgtk, todoist

I am trying to integrate Todoist to Gnome-Todo. I was implementing the OAuth but I'm stuck at the second step after the user grants the access the redirected url doesn't seem to contain the code which needs to be exchanged for access token.

At this page I give grant the access:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/5qEnl.jpg

After this i am redirected to [this page](https://www.google.co.in/?state=test&gws_rd=cr&ei=-9RvWOezC8XJvgSh2ZnYBg) but the url doesn't contain any parameter named code which I need to exchange to get the access token. I also don't know what this `ei` is? Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

The URL doesn't contain `code` because the browser is at your configured `redirect_url`. Browser will be redirected to your configured `redirect_url` after user log into your app and grant the permission.